# Permission Denied - RIDE

Tags: windows, python, pip

Unable to save files in ride 1.7.3.1.  Getting **"Error in serializing. Permission Denied".**

Installed ride using the command "pip install robotframework-ride".

Comment: See if running `chmod +w` or `chmod 777` against the folder you are trying to save to helps any.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue in the Ride. It looks like once you add a test case as .robot and added a manual script, ride have a issue in saving the file as a Test Suite.

I guess this is the issue you are facing :
[Your Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kesl.gif)

***There are two workarounds to resolve the issue***

**Work around 1**

With out adding the test steps soon after you created the test case,

- Create and save the test case name
- Close Ride
- Re-Open ride (*Now you'll be able to add the test cases and save them with out any issue*)
  [Adding Test Suite and Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7dfo.gif)
  [Editing Test Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOnqw.gif)

**Work around 2**

Add the test.robot file manually in your working directly. Then you'll be able to directly edit and save the test cases

[Manual addition of test cases and editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be9uY.gif)

Hope this helps
Cheers